# Singular Value Decomposition for an image understanding

Tags: functional-analysis, approximation, image-processing

I'm trying to get an intuitive understanding of what an SVD decomposition does to an image.

From my understanding, for an image $A \in \Bbb R^{m \times n}$, the singular values are the roots of the eigenvalues of $A^TA$ (or $AA^T$), the left singular vectors are the eigenvectors of $AA^T$ and right singular vectors the eigenvectors of $A^TA$.

What does, for instance, just the first left and right singular vector mean in an image and why are we looking at eigenvectors of $AA^T$ or $A^TA$ - how does this relate to an image? Many thanks!

For example, if we look at this image:

[image]

Looking at the first left singular vector shows an approximation of the intensity values in the image rows:

[image]

Hopefully that makes what I'm asking a little clearer: why does the eigenvectors of $AA^T$ show this relationship?

Comment: Perhaps one of [these interpretations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Intuitive_interpretations) would be useful to you.

Comment: What do you mean by an "image"?  Do you mean that the $i,j$ entry of $A$ is giving us information about the $i,j$ pixel of an image, as in some image file on a computer?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea that you might like: let $\sigma_j$ denote the singular values (diagonal entries of $\Sigma$), $u_j$ the left singular vectors (columns of $U$), $v_j$ the right singular vectors (diagonal entries of $V$).  We then have
$$
A = U \Sigma V^T = \sum_{j=1}^{\min\{m,n\}} \sigma_j u_jv_j^T
$$
That is, we've expressed $A$ as a linear combination (with positive coefficients) of some set of rank-1 matrices $u_jv_j^T$.  These matrices are "mutually orthogonal" in some sense.

Since the singular values are ranked from largest to smallest, the matrices $u_j v_j^T$ are ranked in decreasing order of the prominence of their contribution to $A$.

A common trick in image processing, then, is to only look at the first few.  That is, we make the approximation
$$
A \approx \sum_{j=1}^k \sigma_j u_j v_j^T
$$
for some $k < \min\{m,n\}$.

Comment: Thanks for this - I understand taking the sum of the first few singular values/vectors gives a low rank approximation of the image. What I don't understand is why we are looking at the roots of eigenvalues and the eigenvectors of the image multiplied by its transpose. For instance, If I plotted the first left singular vector as a signal, it gives an approximation of the intensity values of the rows of the image. I'm a bit unsure why it shows this.

Comment: That's because $\sigma_1 u_1v_1^T$ gives us a good rank-1 approximation of the image.

Comment: Potentially helpful things to know about: [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis), [min-max theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem)

Comment: I've added a picture to illustrate what I meant if that's a help. I'm still a bit confused as to why we're looking at $AA^T$.

Comment: The matrix $A^TA$ is relevant because $\|Ax\|^2 = x^T(A^TA)x$.  $AA^T$ necessarily has the same eigenvalues.

Comment: OK, I think I understand now. Many thanks for the time.

Comment: Oh, also: $\|x^TA\|^2 = x^TAA^Tx$